# Запуск макроса VBA из Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2017, ms-word

Необходимо создать кнопку на ленте Word, которая будет запускать макрос расширения vbs. Дизайн ленты и связь с макросом программируется в `visual studio 2017` (windows 7, x64).  В результате на ленте действительно создается кнопка, но при нажатии макрос не запускается. 
При нажатии F5 в `Visual Studio` сборка до конца не производится, появляется сообщение об ошибке. Я думаю, что именно из-за этого макрос не запускается. Как решить эту проблему?

Вот как я осуществила связь кнопки с макросом в `MainRibbon.cs`:

```
private void buttonDelAllReq_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Process pr;
        pr = Process.Start("C:/Users/FlamingPony/Desktop/module1.bas");
        pr.WaitForExit();
    }
```

[image: Не запускается winword.exe из под Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1043778/can-not-run-project-inder-visual-studio-enviroment) советуют запустить VS с настройками по умолчанию, отключить сторонние модули, а так же попробовать выполнить Восстановление.